# Magento redirects to home page after download successfully instead of create admin account page

Tags: magento

At installation of magento through magento downloader after successfully downloading the software it redirects me to home page instead of redirecting to the create admin account page. So my basic problem is i m unable to create an admin account while the process of installation of magento. I m having hard time solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `local.xml` file at the path of `<magento_folder>/app/etc`. Here delete your `local.xml` file and now again reload the magento url in your browser. Now it will redirect you to the installation page. Now you can create your admin account. Try this

Comment: I solved it last day. Though i solved with different way i think your point is also right. By the way i came to know that magento creates a cookie when u first time download it and stores it to the cache of the browser from where u downloaded it. So if you try to download magento using same browser for second time it says "magento has been downloaded earlier" so all that you have to do is just clear the cache of your browser and redownload it from magento website or use another browser for it.

Comment: oh.. I didnt see this type of error messages earlier. But the  solution in the above comment solves your redirection issue??